# «Она думала ответ всю ночь» — правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, управление

Можно ли так сказать: *она думала ответ всю ночь*?

Answer (score 3):

Заглянем в словарь управления (Д. Э. Розенталь):
[думать](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/460/%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
**1.** *что* (полагать, предполагать). Что вы думаете по этому вопросу? Думать думу (фразеологизм).
**2.** *о ком-чем* (размышлять, предаваться раздумью). О ком и о чем вы сейчас думаете? Прости, будь счастлива — и думай иногда... о твоем верном Ибрагиме (Пушкин).
**3.** *о ком-чем* (заботиться, беспокоиться). [Маменька] с утра до вечера об вас думает... чтоб будущее ваше было обеспечено (Салтыков-Щедрин). Нужно было думать о ночлеге (Гайдар).
**4.** *над чем* (направлять мысли на что-л.). Думать над задачей.
**5.** *на кого* (подозревать, считать виновным в чём-л.). — Он нисколько не виноват, а ты на него думаешь, — забормотал Алька (Гайдар).

Правильный выбор таков:
• думала об ответе (*Со своей стороны и миссис Клавдия **думала об ответе** серебряному королю.* Л. Буссенар);
• думала над ответом (*Марина недолго **думала над ответом.*** И. Брестер).

Для винительного падежа можно использовать глагол [обдумывать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/129598) (*что?*):
*Я пару минут **обдумывала ответ*** (О. Карлан);
*Да, я **обдумывал ответ** довольно долго* (К. Берендеев).

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: Она думала об ответе всю ночь.